# Solve the Diophantine equation $a^2(2^a-a^3)+1=7^b$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

The problem is to find all positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2(2^a-a^3)+1=7^b$.

I found a=10, and my intuition tells me there are no more solutions. I've also shown that $a=42k+10$ for some nonnegative integer $k$, but I can't prove anymore than this. (It could help to know that it's from the problems section of a book, so it should have a fairly nice solution.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I see $b$ has to be a multiple of $4$.  Other than that, no idea.

Comment: And a must be even.

Comment: For any positive integer a, LHS is negative and with a positive b, RHS is positive and I don't see how you could solve this?Is the equation by any chance, $(a^{3}-2^{a})$?

Comment: @Arkan Could you please tell us what book this is from? Thanks!

Comment: @satishramanathan $2^a>a^3$ for all $a\geq10$.

Comment: More or less similar to the [Ramanujan-Nagell equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan-Nagell_equation).

Comment: Which theory or context surrounded the exercise? If it's in a chapter on, say, Pell's equations or any other specific subject, could you please mention that? It would help searching in the right direction.

Comment: @Arkan Megraoui Can you tell me the title of that book?

Comment: Well, we have
$$
a^2(2^a-a^3)=7^b-1=6(7^{b-1}+7^{b-2}+\dotsb+1),
$$
and hence $2 \mid a$, say $a=2c$ for an integer $c \ge 1$. Now
\begin{align}
(2c)^2(2^{2c}-(2c)^3) &= 6(7^{b-1}+7^{b-2}+\dotsb+1) \\
2c^2(4^c-8c^3) &= 3(7^{b-1}+7^{b-2}+\dotsb+1).
\end{align}
First assume $3 \mid c$, say $c=3d$ for an integer $d \ge 1$. Then
\begin{align}
2(3d)^2(4^{3d}-8(3d)^3) &= 3(7^{b-1}+7^{b-2}+\dotsb+1)  \\
6d^2(4^{3d}-8(3d)^3) &= 7^{b-1}+7^{b-2}+\dotsb+1.
\end{align}
After working that case out, assume $3 \nmid c$, and work it out.

Does that help?

Comment: Ah, okay... Maybe answer your own question, then, so that it doesn't show up in the "Unanswered" list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP claims to have solved this some time ago (see comment under main question). I'm just adding this answer so that this thread doesn't show up in a "No Answers" search/filter.